# Entity Framework Load Property of Child

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I have the following structure:

```
public class A{}

public Class B:A
{
    public virtual C { get; set;}
}

public Class C{}

public Class Context:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
    public DbSet<C> Cs { get; set; }
}
```

When I want to load any object `b`, the property `C` of this object is null. In the database the column C has an id in the table for `A`. Other `int` or `string` properties can be loaded without a problem.

```
using(var ctx = new Context())
{
    B b = ctx.As.FirstOrDefault() as B;
}
```

Can I solve this problem using lazy loading? Using Eagerly Loading I have a problem to include the property `B`, because I have a list `List<A> someAs` where some of the items are from type `B`.

I tried to keep this example as simple as possible. Just tell me to provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to eagerly load a property of a subclass, you must explicitly query the subclass:

```
ctx.As.OfType<B>().Include(b => b.Cs).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Ah perfect. I think this will do exactly what I want. I am going to try this tomorrow and tell you if it works. One question: why does lazy loading not work in this case?

Comment: Oh, lazy loading should work too if you cast an `A` to a `B`, but IMO eager loading is the preferred approach.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. I couldn't get it to work using lazy loading. I don't want to use it but I am curious. How should I cast `A` to `B`. I tried: `A a = ctx.As.FirstOrDefault();`and then `B b = (B)a` but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can continue using lazy loading and specify to load child relations by using the `.Include()`.
Example:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    // Load all blogs and related posts 
    var blogs1 = context.Blogs 
                        .Include(b => b.Posts) 
                        .ToList(); 

    // Load one blogs and its related posts 
    var blog1 = context.Blogs 
                        .Where(b => b.Name == "ADO.NET Blog") 
                        .Include(b => b.Posts) 
                        .FirstOrDefault(); 

    // Load all blogs and related posts  
    // using a string to specify the relationship 
    var blogs2 = context.Blogs 
                        .Include("Posts") 
                        .ToList(); 

    // Load one blog and its related posts  
    // using a string to specify the relationship 
    var blog2 = context.Blogs 
                       .Where(b => b.Name == "ADO.NET Blog") 
                       .Include("Posts") 
                       .FirstOrDefault(); 
}
```

Take a look at this post:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I cannot use `ctx.As.Include(x => x.C)` because it is not a property of `A`. I have the problem with the inheritance, not with Eagerly Loading in general. Or did I miss something?